# How to set the Button's drawableLeft property in Java code

Tags: android

The **drawableLeft** property of the **Button** class has to be changed to another image when clicked.

What is the equivalent java code for the following xml content.

```
<Button
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/play_button />
```

Comment: button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.play_button, null, null, null), see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play_button);

button.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
```

//button is your button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.play_button);
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),b);
    yourButtonName.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d, null , null , null );
```